# unexpected output from a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

am trying to execute the following code on matlab i've a for loop inside a function and it's supposed to store a result at every iteration ,, but when it executes it just gives me the result of the last iteration,, is there something wrong with the sequence of the code ?
the inpit data1 is a data vector of size (33167*1) 
i doubt that there is sometnig wrong with the foor loop.. there is the code i wrote :

```
function [vectorDominant] = processData(data1 , samplingRate , startRange, endRange)
  %(length(data)/1000)
data = data1;
windowSize = 10;
samplingRate = samplingRate;
frame_len = samplingRate*windowSize;
l = length(data);
num_frames = floor(l/frame_len);
t = 1;

    for i = 1 : num_frames  
                    frame = data( (i-1)*frame_len+1 : frame_len*i);

                    % --- haming window ------

                    hammingData=frame.*hamming(length(frame));

                    %---- remove dc offset from data ----

                    dataWindowed = detrend(hammingData);

                     % ---- apply fft ----


                     fourierTransform_data=fft(dataWindowed);
                     y = fourierTransform_data ;

                     %plot(abs(fourierTransform_data)) 



                     %------- find dominant-----


                 len = (length(frame)/2) -1;

                  y = y(1:len);
                  [v,k] = max(y);


                fftLength = length(frame);
                freq = (0:(samplingRate/fftLength) :(samplingRate/2));


                 %plot(freq,abs(y)), grid('on'), title('dominant freq')
                 freq =  freq(find(freq>=startRange & freq<=endRange));
                 dominantFrequency = freq(k);

                 %array[(length(data)/1000)];
                %var = 1;
                 %while var<= length(num_frames)
                     n = (length(data)/1000);

                     vectorDominant = zeros(n,1);  % to preallocate it first as it changes size every iterartion 
                     vectorDominant(i) = dominantFrequency;
                     %var = var+1;


                   %end



    end


end
```

> the argument i give it is processData(ax, 100, 0.1, 2) where ax is the
>   data vector and it returns the following  ans =
>
> ```
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
>      0
> 0.2000
> ```
>
> the whole result must have numbers like the last one (0.2000) not zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time through the loop you recreate `vectorDominant` to be a vector of zeros and then set one element of it to be the newly calculated value.  Presumably the first 2 of the following lines should be done once before entering the loop.

```
n = (length(data)/1000);
vectorDominant = zeros(n,1);
vectorDominant(i) = dominantFrequency;
```

Presumably `n` should also be `num_frames` not the value calculated above.